# Upgrade to spark2.4.2 from 2.3.1 but mongodb connector stop work

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark

I am using pyspark, today I upgrade the spark and also upgrade the mongodb connector version from org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.2 to
org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.0.

I start pyspark shell with --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.0

But when try to load dataframe from mongodb collection, I got error message

```
>>> df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri", url1).load()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/spark/sparkv2.x/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/home/spark/sparkv2.x/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/spark/sparkv2.x/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/spark/sparkv2.x/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.constructRelation(DefaultSource.scala:91)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Which spark distribution are you using? Spark 2.4.2 switched to Scala 2.12 by default so you'd need to use `org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:2.4.0` unless you specifically used the 2.11 distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed, spark 2.4.2 release notes say it support scala 2.12.x on Java 8, but mine is v2.11.
I upgrade scala version, then restart spark, change the mongodb connector to org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:2.4.0

It works now.